# Return elements in a location corresponding to the minimum values of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays with the same shape in the first two dimensions and I'm looking to record the minimum value in each row of the first array. However I would also like to record the elements in the corresponding position in the third dimension of the second array. I can do it like this:

```
A = np.random.random((5000, 100))
B = np.random.random((5000, 100, 3))

A_mins = np.ndarray((5000, 4))

for i, row in enumerate(A):
    current_min = min(row)
    A_mins[i, 0] = current_min 
    A_mins[i, 1:] = B[i, row == current_min]
```

I'm new to programming (so correct me if I'm wrong) but I understand that with Numpy doing calculations on whole arrays is faster than iterating over them. With this in mind is there a faster way of doing this? I can't see a way to get rid of the `row == current_min` bit even though the location of the minimum point must have been 'known' to the computer when it was calculating the `min()`.

Any tips/suggestions appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along what @lib talked about:

```
index = np.argmin(A, axis=1)
A_mins[:,0] = A[np.arange(len(A)), index]
A_mins[:,1:] = B[np.arange(len(A)), index]
```

It is much faster than using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, would upvote if I had the reputation. Helped with the use of the index too, couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

For getting the index of the minimum value, use amin instead of min + comparison

The amin function (and many other functions in numpy) also takes the argument axis, that you can use to get the minimum of each row or each column.

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html

Comment: Hi @lib, thanks for your response. Sorry I should have mentioned that I was aware of the amin function, however I wasn't sure how to use it to efficiently get the index of the minimum value ie. without using .any().
You prompted me to re-check the references and perhaps you meant to say argmin not amin? That does what I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't spot it before...

Comment: ahah, yes, it was argmin! Initially I was just looking for an example of usage of axis and then it remained the wrong one!